# "BGRT Invalid Status Error 0 Expected 1" followed by permanent loading screen

Tags: linux, hard-disk, manjaro, bios

After I shut down many programs at once using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> in my Linux (Manjaro), my computer froze and I had to force shut it down. Upon rebooting, it gives me the error "BGRT Invalid Status Error 0 Expected 1" and then a permanent typical Manjaro loading screen which takes forever to finish.

Did my hard disk just crash? How can I fix it?